# How to avoid 404 error for a computed property which relies on a variable obtained from API call?

Tags: vue.js, computed-properties

I want to display an image whose source is a computed property which relies on an API call. It works but I get a 404 error message in console which I'd like to not see.

Here's my image:

`<img :src="userPhotoUrl" />`

And here's the computed property and the stuff it depends on:

```
computed: {
  ...mapState({
    user: state => state.dashboard.user || {},
    storageBaseUrl: state => state.storageBaseUrl || ''
  }),
  userPhotoUrl() {
    try {
      return `${this.storageBaseUrl}${this.user.photo}`
    } catch (error) {
      return ""
    }
  }
```

Any idea how to avoid the 404?

Comment: 404 is most likely from the image `src` - cheack your path to image is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the fact that your image makes no sense if there is not a valid url, I would not include it if there is not a valid url

```
<img v-if="baseurl" :src="url" />
```

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {baseurl:false}
})
Vue.use(Vuex)

var vm = new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  store,
  computed: {
    baseurl () { return this.$store.state.baseurl},
    url () { return this.baseurl + '/hn-images/1*Pki08Q31XRtQA8zLl2Gn1w.png'}
  },
  template: '<p><img :src="url" v-if="baseurl"/></p>'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/3.1.2/vuex.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="vm.$store.state.baseurl='https://hackernoon.com'">load baseurl</button>
<div id="app"></div>
```